# Kids and cookies, probability

Tags: probability

10 children $D_1,D_2,...,D_{10}$ were given 20 cookies. What's the probability that $D_{10}$ has at least one cookie if we know that $D_1$ and $D_2$ both have exactly 2 cookies.

I think that by opposite event this can be brought down to the question of what's the probability of placing 16 balls into 8 urns while leaving one (8th) urn empty. But I've no idea what follows.

Comment: Do you know what stars and bars are

Comment: If d1 and d2 have each 2 cookies then there are 16 cookies left. Now we can asume that d10 has only q cookies. Now we want to know how many ways we can give 15 cookies to 8 people

Comment: I will post solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability model is not specified, either explicitly or implicitly. We use as model the following. The cookie giver lines up her $20$ cookies, and for each cookie chooses at random a child to receive it, with all choices equally likely, and with cookie independence.

Given that children 1 and 2 each got $2$, the remaining $8$ got $16$ cookies, with each cookie having probability $\frac{1}{8}$ of landing on a particular child.

The probability that all $16$ cookies avoided child 10 is $\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{16}$, so the probability she got at least one is $1-\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{16}$.

**Remark:** One could assume instead that all "Stars and Bars" distributions are equally likely. That model would give a different (but not terribly different) answer. The model seems less plausible than the multinomial model we used. Well, for cookie distribution neither is plausible. But for database work, where these kinds of calculations find application, the multinomial model is better.